# How run unittest using EcomDev_PHPUnit module?

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests

Here is described old version: http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/02/01/phpunit-and-magento-yes-you-can.html

And they wrote that I need call `phpunit UnitTests.php`

But I have magento v.1.7. I downloaded newest version:
https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit

But there are not any files like UnitTests.php

How I should run unit test then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the neewst available documentation: <strike>http://www.ecomdev.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/EcomDev_PHPUnit-0.2.0-Manual.pdf</strike>

In the current version `EcomDev_PHPUnit` ships with a `phpunit.xml.dist`. Rename this one to `phpunit.xml`, make modifications if necessary and then simply execute `phpunit` without parameters.

Comment: For some reason I got an error then:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(PHP/Invoker.php)'

Comment: Looks like you hit a problem with unit testing Magento. Can you install the PHPunit php-invoker package? Maybe this is related: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/754

Comment: thanks for your help! Phpunit works, I just installed another packages. But phpunit still has an error: http://codepad.org/k7lmQucJ. (I didn't create any test for a while) What is the problem colud be here?

Comment: Okay - that is one of the tests which are integrated in EcomDev itself that fails. But having a look at the line https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/blob/master/app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnitTest/Test/Lib/Constraint/Config/Resource/Script.php#L57 it seems that EcomDev can not load the matching expection file from https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/blob/master/app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnitTest/Test/Lib/Constraint/Config/Resource/expectations/testParseVersions.yaml. (Expected is empty, but actual has data)

Comment: The key here is to run "phpunit" at the main folder, not at /shell. You usually follow the steps in the example, but they simply doesn't tell you to go back to main path. :)

Answer (score 6):

there is no need. just run `phpunit` it wil find the `phpunit.xml.dist`(as fallback) automatically and use the configuration in this file.