# Pointers to write unit test cases using EcomDev_PHPUnit

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests

I am trying to implement a web service client for one of my module and I would like to test it using EcomDev_PHPUnit. So, I have a "Test" folder inside my module with following structure...

```
- Webservice
-- Clientservice
---Model
----Callservice.php
--- Test
----Model
-----Callservice.php
```

My `"Callservice.php"` has a `"httpRequest()"` function that does `Mage::log("Hello world!");`
And as I am testing a service, I don't need any fixtures as of now...

But when I try to run "phpunit UnitTests.php"...I see a series of errors.The first few lines are about EcomDev_PHPUnitTest module I think we can ignore it safely. The other errors says that

```
Warning
There is no module with name: webservice_clientservice
```

My config.xml top most few lines are as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Webservice_Clientservice>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Webservice_Clientservice>
    </modules>
  ...
  ...
 <phpunit>
    <suite>
        <modules>
             <Webservice_Clientservice />
        </modules>
        <groups>
            <model>Model</model>
        </groups>
    </suite>
 </phpunit>
 </config>
```

My module xml file is Webservice_Clientservice.xml as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Webservice_Clientservice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>

            </depends>
        </Webservice_Clientservice>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

And when I use phpunit --filter <> UnitTests.php, I see the below -

```
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.



Time: 1 second, Memory: 14.75Mb

No tests executed!
```

That leaves me perfectly confused. How do I write test cases(without test suites and later with test suites) in EcomDev_PHPUnit? Any pointers or same modules would be really great. Thanks!

***Well it worked with the following:***

I had missed a file `"phpunit.xml.dist"` in the magento root directory, not just that. I had to comment out a few lines in `UnitTests.php` in the magento root directory too - after which it looks as below -

```
<?php

//bootstrap.php already does this, not sure why we would need it here again
/*require 'app/Mage.php';

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '<')) {
    exit('Magento Unit Tests can be runned only on PHP version over 5.3');
}

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    exit('Magento Unit Tests can be runned only on installed version');
}

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'index.php';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'index.php';

Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getConfig()->init();*/

class UnitTests extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Suite
{

}
```

so now I see the log entry in mage system.log :)

Well, I am not yet sure if this is the right way...comments welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [How run unittest using EcomDev\_PHPUnit module?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/how-run-unittest-using-ecomdev-phpunit-module)

Comment: @Marius : It is not...Well I did see that post but the solution did not work, hence not an duplicate...And that question was about initial set up and this is about how exactly to write tests using EcomDev_PHPUnit after set up...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read the documentation of the module which can be found here

http://www.ecomdev.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/EcomDev_PHPUnit-0.2.0-Manual.pdf

Anyway, to answer your question, your configuration is not correct. In your `config.xml` you should tell EcomDev_PHPUnit about your module, like this:

```
<config>
    ...
    <phpunit>
        <suite>
            <modules>
                <Webservice_Clientservice />
            </modules>
        </suite>
    </phpunit>
    ...
</config>
```

Now you can run your tests by calling

```
phpunit --group Webservice_Clientservice
```

Comment: Oops I am sorry I forgot to mention that..I do have that configuration in my config.xml..I will update my question